# C - fully threaded binary search trees

Tags: c, tree, reinventing-the-wheel

For learning purposes, I've decided to implement several classic data structures, starting with binary search trees. The entire code can be seen [here](https://github.com/mpevnev/miscellany), in a frozen branch `review-btree-21.12.2017`. So far I've implemented basic functionality - search/insert/delete and the two simplest traversals. Advanced functionality - rebalancing, reordering, conversion from and to lists and such - will be the stuff for another question, which will also incorporate whatever advice I'll get for this one.

This is based on a tutorial by Eternally Confuzzled (there are differences, for instance, he made his trees only partially threaded). The most important thing is that instead of having two variables for left and right link of the tree, an array is used, where 0 means left, and 1 means right. I find it convenient and elegant.

My main concerns are:

- Efficiency - do my procedures perform as well as binary trees allow it?
- Threading - is it broken? The tests I've devised do not reveal any errors (they did, but I fixed those), but that's hardly an indication of their absense.

In the `test` directory of the repo with the source there's the test driver I've used to check all of this. It uses `check` library, so make sure you have it installed if you want to run the tests. I won't post testing code here unless asked (feel free to do so), since there's enough of code clutter going on below already.

Now for the code. Here's (most of) the header file:

```
#ifndef BTREE_H
#define BTREE_H

/** A binary tree module. 
 *
 * Based on a tutorial by Eternally Confuzzled. 
 *
 */

/* ---------- base stuff ---------- */

enum btt_type
{
    BTT_INORDER,
    BTT_INORDER_REV,
};

struct btree
{
    void *data;
    /* 0 for left, 1 for right. */
    int thread[2];
    struct btree *link[2]; /* A threaded link or a child. */
};

/* btt - binary tree traversal */
struct btt
{
    enum btt_type type;
    struct btree *tree, *cur;
};

/* These should return a negative value if (left < right), 0 if (left == right)
 * and a positive value if (left > right). 
 * */
typedef int (*btree_cmp_fn)(void *left, void *right);
typedef int (*btree_cmp_ex_fn)(void *left, void *right, void *external_arg);

/* ---------- creation ---------- */

extern struct btree *
btree_create(void *data);

/* ---------- destruction ---------- */

/* Note that you can freely destroy subtrees, the parent tree (if there's one)
 * will be updated to exclude the destroyed subtree. */

extern void 
btree_destroy(struct btree *);

extern void
btree_destroy_ex(struct btree *, void (*destroyer)(void *data));

extern void 
btree_destroy_exx(struct btree *, void (*destroyer)(void *data, void *arg), void *arg);

/* ---------- traversal ---------- */

extern struct btt *
btt_create(struct btree *tree, enum btt_type type);

/* A non-allocating version of the above. */
extern void
btt_init(struct btt *btt, struct btree *tree, enum btt_type type);

extern int
btt_done(struct btt *btt);

extern void *
btt_this(struct btt *btt);

extern struct btree *
btt_this_node(struct btt *btt);

extern void *
btt_next(struct btt *);

extern struct btree *
btt_next_node(struct btt *);

extern void
btt_rewind(struct btt *);

extern void
btt_destroy(struct btt *);

/* Finalize a traversal without freeing its memory (just its state's memory, if
 * any, will be freed) */
extern void
btt_fin(struct btt *);

/* ---------- accessing struct members and information retrieval ---------- */

extern void *
btree_data(struct btree *tree);

extern struct btree *
btree_left(struct btree *tree);

extern struct btree *
btree_right(struct btree *tree);

extern int
btree_thread(struct btree *tree, int dir);

extern struct btree *
btree_link(struct btree *tree, int dir);

extern int
btree_has_children(struct btree *);

extern int
btree_has_child(struct btree *, int dir);

extern int
btree_num_children(struct btree *);

extern int
btree_is_a_leaf(struct btree *);

/* Return the index of the link in the links array of the given tree, or -1 if
 * the link is not there. */
extern int
btree_link_dir(struct btree *tree, struct btree *link);

extern size_t
btree_size(struct btree *tree);

/* ---------- searching ---------- */

/* Return 1 if the element was found (and fill res with it), return 0 and do
 * nothing with 'res' otherwise. Pass NULL as 'res' to avoid filling it with
 * anything. */
extern int
btree_find(struct btree *tree, void *data, btree_cmp_fn cmp, void **res);

/* Return 1 if the element was found (and fill res with it), return 0 and do
 * nothing with 'res' otherwise. Pass NULL as 'res' to avoid filling it with
 * anything. */
extern int
btree_find_ex(struct btree *tree, void *data, btree_cmp_ex_fn cmp, void *cmp_arg, void **res);

extern struct btree *
btree_find_node(struct btree *tree, void *data, btree_cmp_fn cmp);

extern struct btree *
btree_find_node_ex(struct btree *tree, void *data, btree_cmp_ex_fn cmp, void *cmp_arg);

extern struct btree *
btree_parent(struct btree *tree);

/* Note that this searches for a successor of the entire subtree. */
extern struct btree *
btree_successor(struct btree *tree);

/* Note that this searches for a predecessor of the entire subtree. */
extern struct btree *
btree_predecessor(struct btree *tree);

/* Return either left or right outermost subnode of the subtree. */
extern struct btree *
btree_outermost(struct btree *tree, int dir);

/* Return either predecessor of the leftmost subnode or a successor of the 
 * rightmost subnode. */
extern struct btree *
btree_after_outermost(struct btree *tree, int dir);

/* ---------- insertion ---------- */

/* Return the freshly created node, or NULL on an OOM condition. */
extern struct btree *
btree_insert(struct btree *tree, void *data, btree_cmp_fn cmp);

/* Return the freshly created node, or NULL on an OOM condition. */
extern struct btree *
btree_insert_ex(struct btree *tree, void *data, btree_cmp_ex_fn cmp, void *arg);

/* ---------- deletion ---------- */

/* There's no function to delete subtrees - this is done either with
 * btree_destroy family or btree_unlink. */

/* + Return 1 if the data was found in the tree, 0 otherwise. 
 * + Fill 'tree_after' * with the tree after the deletion of the data (might be
 * NULL if the last node in the tree was deleted). Pass NULL to avoid filling.
 * + Fill 'deleted' with the data from the tree that was deleted (not from the
 * 'data' argument! they might be different depending on what 'cmp' function
 * does). Pass NULL to avoid filling. */
extern int
btree_delete(struct btree *tree, void *data, btree_cmp_fn cmp, 
        struct btree **tree_after, void **deleted);

/* Ditto, but cmp takes an extra argument. */
extern int
btree_delete_ex(struct btree *tree, void *data, btree_cmp_ex_fn cmp, void *arg,
        struct btree **tree_after, void **deleted);

/* ---------- other ---------- */

/* Unlink the given subtree from its tree. */
extern void
btree_unlink(struct btree *tree);

#endif /* BTREE_H */
```

I will omit `_ex` versions of most functions here to save space, they only differ from ordinary versions in that the function they accept as an argument takes an extra `void *` argument, so one doesn't have to use globals.

Here's the creation function, mostly boilerplate:

```
struct btree *
btree_create(void *data)
{
    struct btree *res = malloc(sizeof(struct btree));
    if (res == NULL) return NULL;

    res->data = data;
    res->thread[0] = 0;
    res->thread[1] = 0;
    res->link[0] = NULL;
    res->link[1] = NULL;

    return res;
}
```

Destructor function and its helper procedure, `btree_unlink` (which removes threading and child connections between a tree and its parent tree). The reason for the `DESTROY_BODY` macro is that there are two more functions for tree destructions which only differ in a single line, where freeing tree data takes place.

```
#define DESTROY_BODY(tree, free_data) \
{ \
    if (tree == NULL) return; \
    btree_unlink(tree); \
 \
    tree = btree_outermost(tree, 0); \
    while (tree != NULL) { \
        struct btree *link = tree->link[1]; \
        int thread = tree->thread[1]; \
        free_data; \
        free(tree); \
        tree = link; \
        if (!thread && link != NULL) { \
            while (!tree->thread[0] && tree->link[0] != NULL) \
                tree = tree->link[0]; \
        } \
    } \
} \

void
btree_destroy(struct btree *tree)
{
    DESTROY_BODY(tree, (void) 0);
}

void
btree_unlink(struct btree *tree)
{
    struct btree *left = btree_outermost(tree, 0);
    struct btree *right = btree_outermost(tree, 1);

    /* Make the outer tree forget about the inner. */
    struct btree *before_left = left->link[0];
    struct btree *after_right = right->link[1];
    if (before_left != NULL && (before_left->thread[1] || before_left->link[1] == tree)) {
        before_left->thread[1] = after_right != NULL;
        before_left->link[1] = after_right;
    }
    if (after_right != NULL && (after_right->thread[0] || after_right->link[0] == tree)) {
        after_right->thread[0] = before_left != NULL;
        after_right->link[0] = before_left;
    }

    /* Make the inner tree a standalone tree. */
    left->thread[0] = 0;
    left->link[0] = NULL;
    right->thread[1] = 0;
    right->link[1] = NULL;
}
```

Searching is done pretty much as one would expect it from binary trees:

```
struct btree *
btree_find_node(struct btree *tree, void *data, btree_cmp_fn cmp)
{
    if (tree == NULL) return NULL;
    while(1) {
        int cmp_res = cmp(data, tree->data);
        if (cmp_res == 0) return tree;

        int dir = cmp_res > 0;
        if (tree->thread[dir] || tree->link[dir] == NULL) return NULL;
        tree = tree->link[dir];
    }
}
```

Insertion is slightly trickier because of threading (again, the reason for `INSERT_BODY` macro is that the only difference between `btree_insert` and `btree_insert_ex` is a single line where comparison takes place).

```
#define INSERT_BODY(tree, data, cmp, cmp_line) \
{ \
    struct btree *res = btree_create(data); \
    if (res == NULL) return NULL; \
 \
    while (1) { \
        int cmp_res = cmp_line; \
        int dir = cmp_res > 0; \
        if (tree->link[dir] == NULL || tree->thread[dir]) { \
            struct btree *old_link = tree->link[dir]; \
            /* If a node is inserted to the right, it gets its \
             * parent's right thread and the parent as its left \
             * thread. If a node is inserted to the left, the  \
             * situation is mirrored. */ \
            res->thread[dir] = old_link != NULL; \
            res->link[dir] = old_link; \
            res->thread[!dir] = 1; \
            res->link[!dir] = tree; \
            /* The parent gets the created node as its child. */ \
            tree->thread[dir] = 0; \
            tree->link[dir] = res; \
            /* The threaded node, if it exists, gets threaded to \
             * the inserted node if it doesn't have a child in this \
             * direction. */ \
            if (old_link == NULL) return res; \
            if (!old_link->thread[!dir]) return res; \
            old_link->thread[!dir] = 1; \
            old_link->link[!dir] = res; \
            return res; \
        } else { \
            tree = tree->link[dir]; \
        } /* if found insertion location */ \
    } /* while 1 */ \
} 

struct btree *
btree_insert(struct btree *tree, void *data, btree_cmp_fn cmp)
{
    INSERT_BODY(tree, data, cmp, cmp(data, tree->data));
}
```

Now for deletion. Again `DELETE_BODY` helps to avoid code duplication between `btree_delete` and `btree_delete_ex`.

```
#define DELETE_BODY(tree, data, cmp, tree_after, deleted, find) \
{ \
    if (tree_after != NULL) *tree_after = tree; \
    if (deleted != NULL) *deleted = NULL; \
    if (tree == NULL) return 0; \
 \
    struct btree *to_delete = find; \
    if (to_delete == NULL) return 0; \
    void *old_data = to_delete->data; \
 \
    /* The simplest case - the node is a leaf. */ \
    if (btree_is_a_leaf(to_delete)) { \
        btree_unlink(to_delete); \
        if (tree_after != NULL) *tree_after = tree == to_delete ? NULL : tree; \
        if (deleted != NULL) *deleted = old_data; \
        free(to_delete); \
        return 1; \
    } \
 \
    /* A bit harder - the node has a single child. */ \
    if (btree_num_children(to_delete) == 1) { \
        int child_dir = btree_has_child(to_delete, 1); \
        /* Simply replace the node with its child. */ \
        struct btree *child = to_delete->link[child_dir]; \
        struct btree *parent = btree_parent(to_delete); \
        if (parent == NULL) { \
            child->thread[!child_dir] = 0; \
            child->link[!child_dir] = 0; \
            if (tree_after != NULL) *tree_after = child; \
            if (deleted != NULL) *deleted = old_data; \
            free(to_delete); \
            return 1; \
        } else { \
            int dir_to_here = btree_link_dir(parent, to_delete); \
            parent->thread[dir_to_here] = 0; \
            parent->link[dir_to_here] = child; \
            child->thread[!child_dir] = 1; \
            child->link[!child_dir] = parent; \
            free(to_delete); \
            if (tree_after != NULL) *tree_after = parent; \
            if (deleted != NULL) *deleted = old_data; \
            return 1; \
        } /* if parent is null */ \
    } /* if the node has one child */ \
 \
    /* The last case - both children are present. Pretty easy to do, \
     * actually - find inorder predecessor and replace the node with it. */ \
    struct btree *left_child = to_delete->link[0]; \
    struct btree *predecessor = btree_outermost(left_child, 1); \
    btree_unlink(predecessor); \
    to_delete->data = predecessor->data; \
    if (tree_after != NULL) *tree_after = tree; \
    if (deleted != NULL) *deleted = old_data; \
    free(predecessor); \
    return 1; \
} \

extern int
btree_delete(struct btree *tree, void *data, btree_cmp_fn cmp, 
        struct btree **tree_after, void **deleted)
{
    DELETE_BODY(tree, data, cmp, tree_after, deleted, 
            btree_find_node(tree, data, cmp));
}
```

Trees being fully threaded has a benefit of making inorder and reverse inorder traversals very easy:

```
/* Helper functions. */

struct btree *
btt_next_inorder(struct btt *btt)
{
    struct btree *cur = btt->cur;
    if (cur->thread[1]) {
        btt->cur = cur->link[1];
    } else {
        cur = cur->link[1];
        while (cur != NULL && !cur->thread[0] && cur->link[0] != NULL) 
            cur = cur->link[0];
        btt->cur = cur;
    }
    return btt->cur;
}

struct btree *
btt_next_inorder_rev(struct btt *btt)
{
    struct btree *cur = btt->cur;
    if (cur->thread[0]) {
        btt->cur = cur->link[0];
    } else {
        cur = cur->link[0];
        while (cur != NULL && !cur->thread[1] && cur->link[1] != NULL) 
            cur = cur->link[1];
        btt->cur = cur;
    }
    return btt->cur;
}

/* Exported functions. */

struct btt *
btt_create(struct btree *tree, enum btt_type type)
{
    struct btt *res = malloc(sizeof(struct btt));
    if (res == NULL) return NULL;

    btt_init(res, tree, type);
    return res;
}

void
btt_init(struct btt *btt, struct btree *tree, enum btt_type type)
{
    btt->tree = tree;
    btt->type = type;
    switch (type) {
        case BTT_INORDER:
            btt->cur = btree_outermost(tree, 0);
            break;
        case BTT_INORDER_REV:
            btt->cur = btree_outermost(tree, 1);
            break;
    } /* switch type */
}

int
btt_done(struct btt *btt)
{
    return btt->cur == NULL;
}

void *
btt_this(struct btt *btt)
{
    return btt->cur->data;
}

struct btree *
btt_this_node(struct btt *btt)
{
    return btt->cur;
}

void *
btt_next(struct btt *btt)
{
    return btt_next_node(btt)->data;
}

struct btree *
btt_next_node(struct btt *btt)
{
    switch (btt->type) {
        case BTT_INORDER: return btt_next_inorder(btt);
        case BTT_INORDER_REV: return btt_next_inorder_rev(btt);
    }
}

void
btt_rewind(struct btt *btt)
{
    btt_fin(btt);
    btt_init(btt, btt->tree, btt->type);
}

void
btt_destroy(struct btt *btt)
{
    btt_fin(btt);
    free(btt);
}

void
btt_fin(struct btt *btt)
{
    /* TODO: btt_fin: clear up any state. */
}
```

For an example of usage of all of the above, as well as some helper functions that have been used here and there, please see the source in the repo and `test` directory. I'm afraid there's too much code in the question already (if there isn't, just say so, I'll add whatever is needed).

Comment: Hi! I´m no senior at Code Review but fell that the code posted is kind of intimidating because of its shear size. You could reduce lines-of-code significantly in many places, skipping "boilerplate indentation" for simple functions in the last code snippet for example. Code comments are good but should ADD infromation, not repeat the obvious. No help to you question but maybe someone else will find reviewing it more pleasant... Anyway, good luck!